# Hierarchy in REST API for a catalogue

Tags: rest

I have a application which has a catalogue.

I have the Category,Sub-Category and Sub-Sub category.

I can PUT the contect by using the Sub-Sub-Category ID Directly and it takes the Hierarchy.

What I am looking for is for the application to let me choose Category and once selected give me Sub-category and once selected to give sub-sub category.

Regards
MG

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some details about the REST API you are calling and ideally include an example of what you wish to achieve. Currently it's very difficult to answer your question, as it is quite vague.

Comment: "problemtype": {
        "id": 474,
        "type": "RequestType",
        "detailDisplayName": "Stakeholder Requests ; Network"

In the above comments. 474 represents Network, Where as it comes under Stakeholder Requests which is 27. 
when I run POST with 474 it takes the hirarchy, but what I need is for the mobile application to give me 27 and then select the subtypes under 27.